# Draw coins (without replacement) at random

Tags: statistics, probability

I am running into a problem that asks me to calculate the probability and standard deviation. The problem is follows:

> Coins with values 1 through N (inclusive) are placed into a bag. All the coins from the bag are iteratively drawn (without replacement) at random. For the first coin, you are paid the value of the coin. For subsequent coins, you are paid the absolute difference between the drawn coin and the previously drawn coin. For example, if you drew 5,3,2,4,1
>   , your payments would be 5,2,1,2,3
>    for a total payment of 13
>   .

1. What is the standard deviation of your total payment for N=20?
2. What is the probability that your total payment is greater than or equal to 160 for N=20?

Can I get your help with these two questions? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Please edit your question to also explain how specifically you are having trouble with these questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.